# Queue threading status progress

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to create a web extractor, I have this code for multithreads, and I need print the status/progress of the scanner :

```
import time
import threading
import Queue       
import sys

try:
    Lista = open(sys.argv[1], "r").readlines()
except(IOError): 
    print "Error: Check your ip list path\n"
    sys.exit(1)

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread) :

    def __init__(self, queue) :
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self) :
        while True :
            counter = self.queue.get()
            sys.stdout.write("line nr : \r")
            self.queue.task_done()      

queue = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(50) :
    worker = WorkerThread(queue)
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

for line in Lista:
    queue.put(line)

queue.join()

print "All task over!"
```

How can I print the status/progress when the scanner working, I'm tried `len(queue)` but it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you explain a bit why `len(queue)` is not correct?

Comment: @OfirIsrael: `Queue`s don't have lengths, so you get a `TypeError` or `AttributeError` depending on your Python version, and presumably he doesn't consider that a correct way to get information for a progress bar…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Queue` objects do not have a `len` because, by their very nature, they're being shared across threads, and it would be inaccurate and misleading.

However, they have a [`qsize`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.qsize) method that gives you the approximate size, for exactly this kind of purpose.

---

If you want *exact* values, you need a second `Queue` for that, where each task puts something on the out-queue, and some extra thread (or possibly the main thread) loops over it and counts up the tasks done so far. Or, alternatively, something simpler, like a global `int` counter with a global `Lock` protecting it.

---

However, I think it would be a lot simpler to write this in terms of a pool or executor. That would take care of queueing up tasks for you, and returning a value for each one to the main thread, without you needing to manage anything. For example, using [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures), the backport of the Python 3.x [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module for 2.x, here's your whole program, with progress added:

```
import sys
import futures 

try:
    Lista = open(sys.argv[1], "r").readlines()
except(IOError): 
    print "Error: Check your ip list path\n"
    sys.exit(1)

def task(line):
    # Do something

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(50) as executor:
    fs = [executor.submit(task, line) for line in Lista]
    for i, f in enumerate(futures.as_completed(fs)):
        sys.stdout.write("line nr: {} / {} \r".format(i, len(Lista)))

print "All task over!"
```